# Wy is the menu flickering on mobile device

Tags: jquery

On mobile devices (only tested on Sony Xperia, Android) on tap/tuch the entire menu is flickering in a blue color.

This is only visable on mobile devices.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/b1913dLq/)

[Live demo](http://test3.fcab.se/responsive_menu_test/simple_multi_responsive_menu_flat/index.html)
     
     This is the js code i use to controll the menu:

```
;(function($) {

// DOM ready
$(function() {

// Add some classes and Append the mobile icon nav
$('.nav').append($('<div class="nav-mobile"></div>'));
$('.nav > ul').addClass('nav-list');
$('.nav > ul > li').addClass('nav-item');
$('.nav > ul > li > ul').addClass('nav-submenu');
$('.nav > ul > li > ul > li').addClass('nav-submenu-item');

// Add a <span> to every .nav-item that has a <ul> inside. And add an sub menu icon indicator.
$('.nav-item').has('ul').prepend('<span class="nav-click"><i></i>  </span>');

// Click to reveal the mobile menu
$('.nav-mobile').click(function(){
$('.nav-list').toggle();
$('.nav-submenu').hide(); // This will close the submenu when i click the top ribbon (.nav-mobile) to close the mobile menu
if(!$('.nav-list').is(':visible')){ // the menu was closed because it's not visible anymore
$('.nav-item .nav-click').each(function(){ // loop through nav clicks
if($(this).hasClass('icon-close')) { // This will toggle back the + icon on mobile menu close/open
$(this).toggleClass('icon-close');           
}
}); 
}
});

// Dynamic binding to on 'click' and Toggle the nested nav
$('.nav-list').on('click', '.nav-click', function(){
var currentSubmenu = $(this).siblings('.nav-submenu');
var currentNavClick = $(this);
$('.nav-submenu').not(currentSubmenu).hide();
$('.nav-click').not(currentNavClick).removeClass('icon-close');
$(this).siblings('.nav-submenu').toggle();

// This will toggle the + and - when clicked
$(this).removeClass('nav-click');
$(this).toggleClass('icon-close');
$(this).toggleClass('nav-click');   
});

// This will toggle the menu/submenu/- when click outside of the menu
$('.wrapper').click(function(event) {
$('html').one('click',function() {
$('.nav-list').hide();
$('.nav-submenu').hide(); // This will close the submenu when you click the top ribbon (hamburger button) to close the mobile menu
if(!$('.nav-list').is(':visible')){ // the menu was closed because it's not visible anymore
$('.nav-item .nav-click').each(function(){ // loop through nav clicks
if($(this).hasClass('icon-close')) { // This will toggle the +/- icon on mobile menu close/open
$(this).toggleClass('icon-close');
}
}); 
}
});
event.stopPropagation();
});

}); 
})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ahha, i fixed it like this:

```
*{
-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
}
```